# Convert elements in a List to Title-Case?

Tags: c#, list, title-case

I am trying to convert all list items to TitleCase.  I thought TitleCase would be simple, but it does not seem to work the same as uppercase or lowercase.  Any ideas?  This is what works for upper and lower:

List myList = new List() { "abc", "DEF", "Def", "aBC" };

```
myList = myList.ConvertAll(x => x.ToUpper());
myList = myList.ConvertAll(x => x.ToLower());
```

but neither of these work:

```
myList = myList.ConvertAll(x => x.ToTitleCase());
myList = myList.ConvertAll(x => x.TitleCase());
```

Comment: What is the definition of `myList`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) method.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "abc", "DEF", "Def", "aBC" };
CultureInfo currentCulture =  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
myList = myList.Select(r=> currentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(r.ToLower())).ToList();
```

output:

```
foreach (string str in myList)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Result:

```
Abc
Def
Def
Abc
```

EDIT:

You can use ConvetAll like:

```
myList =  myList.ConvertAll(r => currentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(r.ToLower()));
```

Comment: You need to call ToLower first; ToTitleCase leaves uppercase letters untouched.

Comment: Habib, your method worked perfectly...after i added 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture'.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "abc", "DEF", "Def", "aBC" };

            CultureInfo currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            myList=myList.ConvertAll(r => currentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(r.ToLower()));
            int i=0;
            myList.ForEach(delegate(string k)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(k);
                 i++;
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if original values are uppercase, you have to drop to lower. You may also need to add Globalization namespace. I used this in a DropDownList_DataBound event.

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;        
foreach (ListItem li in DropDownList.Items)
{
     li.Text = currentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(li.Text.ToLower());
}
```